# Dtmf based robot

Tags: microcontroller

Does any one know any thing about connecting the audio phone jack to micro-controller.
I am making a DTMF based mobile controlled robot and i do not know how to connect a 3.5mm audio phone jack to micro-controller. I do not know the colored wires connections. Somebody help me out please.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about what you are trying to do. The audio jack will carry an audible, dual-tone signal. What do you need the microcontroller to do with it? Presumably apply it to an ADC pin (after clamping it to the microcontroller's max voltage), and use the digitized sound stream to determine the tones sent to it. The question seems to indicate that this clarity is lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually [this pinout: ground on the barrel, audio on the tip and ring.](http://pinouts.ru/Home/Tele35s_pinout.shtml)

If you have some wires coming from a cut plug, use a multimeter in resistance testing mode touched to the plug to work out which is which.

Comment: I have tried it by using its fiber, But it's not working. Is there any other way to find out?

Comment: @SubayyalSheikh "*it's not working*" - In what way, and what did you expect "it" to do?

Comment: I want to attach the audio jack colored wires to the DTMF IC circuit. but when i try to check the connections using DMM (to check the mic+ and speaker ground wires) it does not show any response in DMM i.e it does not show where it is short.

Answer (score -4):

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=4618331

http://seminarprojects.com/s/dtmf-controlled-robot

you can also google for more links ...

Comment: Link-only answers are not really useful: Please take the effort to at least put, in your own words, an abstract of the link contents, and an explanation of why *that* particular link. Also, if the linked site dies or gets rearranged some day, the answer becomes meaningless. *Anyone* can google for more links, that's not really meaningful content for an answer.